# Default field value check in qfield form

Tags: qfield, default

Using Qfield Project, in the input data form is always avaible for all field the check to set the default value for the next features.
It is possible with some settings define if this check will be available or not for each field?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (QField 1.1.1) it is not possible to control this checkbox per attribute.